# Galerkin method in Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

I've got this problem to solve:

Using Galerkin method, prove that there exists a weak solution of this differential equation:

$$-\Delta u = a(x) \circ \triangledown u - u_t +f(x)$$ on $\Omega$

$$u = 0$$ on $\partial \Omega$

$$u(x,0)=u_{0}(x)$$

where $f,u_0\in L^{1}(\Omega), a\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ are known.

I started with using definition of a weak solution. If $u\in W^{1,2}_{0}(\Omega)$ is a solution of the problem above (where $W^{1,2}_{0}(\Omega)$ is a Sobolev space with inner product defined $<f,g>=\int_{\Omega}\triangledown f\circ \triangledown g)$ then:

$$\forall \varphi \in W^{1,2}_{0}(\Omega) \int_{\Omega}\triangledown u \circ\triangledown \varphi -\int_{\Omega}(a(x)\circ\triangledown u) \varphi +\int_{\Omega}u_t\varphi = \int_{\Omega}f\varphi $$

Then I defined $W_m \subset W^{1,2}_{0}(\Omega)$ such that:

$$ W_m = lin\{\varphi_1,...,\varphi_m\} $$

where $\varphi_i$ are orthonormal. Let $u_m \in W_m$ be the solution of the problem above. We can write:

$$ u_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m}c_k^m\varphi_k$$

To finish the solution I need to know the coefficients $c^m_i$ and I have no idea how to do this. Thank you in advance for any help!